# Is there a way to wrap text in an EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am setting the texts inside of EditTexts in Java. Right now, what happens is, when the text is long, it just gets cut off.

In the XML, the height of the EditText is set to wrap_content. I want the height to change depending on the length of the String I will place in it so that all the text can be seen. Any solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Edit: My EditText's setup

```
<item name="android:layout_width">310dp</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:padding">15dp</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center</item>
<item name="android:editable">false</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/color_darktext</item>
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/color_hint</item>
<item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
<item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">8dp</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/button50radius</item>
<item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
<item name="android:inputType">none</item>
```

Comment: did you set `isSingleLine="true"` to your edit text ???

Comment: none. edited my post with my EditText's setup @Kathi

Answer (score 0):

> The height of the EditText is set to wrap_content

That means it will be wrapped properly how ever long your text is, It doesn't matter.

> Any solution for this ?

Yes there are some possibilities, You have not posted your XML so that it would be hard to recognize the mistake. But one of the possibility is

- Your parent layout which is containing the `TextView` may be having the `paddingBottom` attribute so that your `TextView` won't be able to show the full text inside.

If the above one is not what you did in your case, Then you can add[`android:layout_gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) attribute,

> It is Standard gravity constant that a child supplies to its parent. Defines how the child view should be positioned, on both the X and Y axes, within its enclosing layout.

You can set it to `android:layout_gravity="fill"` which will grow the horizontal and vertical size of the object if needed so it completely fills its container.

Comment: i have included my EditText's setup in question :)

Comment: Try removing padding then

Comment: @Yeol And if still problem exists then try adding `<item name="android:layout_gravity">fill</item>` as well

Comment: It still wont work for me, sadly :( But thank you for the help :)

Comment: What I can suggest is try removing `android:stateListAnimator` `android:background` one by one. It would work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be your `padding` and restricting the `width` of the `EditText`.Please do change those values and you can notice the difference.Try changing the width to `wrap_content` and add the attribute `maxWidth="310dp"` to restrict your width.

Answer (score 0):

also set the parent layout, Layout_width property . 
For example 
`layout_width=250sp`

otherwise , EditText or TextView dont wrap to next line till it reach the end of mobile border. So define the Layout_width